# What happened to Gideon?

Tags: discussion

So, I can't make Gideon flip my words and sort people anymore! What happened? Did anyone complain or something?

Please someone fix it soon.

Comment: [Bot Rules](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24360544#24360544).

Comment: all better. nothing to see here.

Answer (score -2):

So basically,

I started to sort too many people. Then @KutuluMike and 2 mods got annoyed (I presume).

Then, as @KutuluMike bravely tried to stop it, the bot kept on crashing.<sub>1</sub>

So it will return soon, after KutuluMike fixes it, and I apologize to anyone I annoyed.

<sub>1 I had nothing to do with that.</sub>